# Trouble with this probability identity: $\operatorname{E} \bigl[ (Z - E[Z]) \bigr]^2 = \operatorname{var}(X) + \operatorname{var}(Y)$

Tags: probability, variance

My professor recently surprised us with a pop quiz on probability, and I'm struggling to prove a particular identity involving random variables. Suppose we have two independent random variables, $X$ and $Y$, and define another random variable $Z$ as $Z = X - Y$. I am trying to prove the following expression:
$$
\operatorname{E} \bigl[ (Z - E[Z]) \bigr]^2 
= \operatorname{var}(X) + \operatorname{var}(Y) 
$$

The presence of the square outside the expected value is confusing me, even though I confirmed with my professor that it should be there. Can someone guide me through this proof? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your professor told you the wrong thing. What you should have is that $\operatorname{Var}(X-Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26886/why-is-the-variance-of-x-y-equal-to-the-sum-of-the-variances-when-x-y-are-in)

Comment: The left side of the equation should read $\operatorname{E}\bigl[ (Z - \operatorname{E}(Z))^2 \bigr]$, as this is the variance of the variable $Z$. The square belongs inside, since the variance is the expected value of the *squared* deviation.

Answer (score 2):

The square outside is definitely wrong, because $E(Z-E(Z))^2=(E(Z)-E(E(Z))^2=(E(Z)-E(Z))^2=0$ which can only be equal to $Var(X)+Var(Y)$ if both $X$ and $Y$ are almost surely constant. If it is inside, we have
\begin{align*}E((Z-E(Z))^2)&=E((X-Y)^2-(E(X-Y))^2)\\
&=E((X-Y)^2)-(E(X-Y))^2\\
&=E(X^2-2XY+Y^2)-(E(X)-E(Y))^2\\
&=E(X^2)-2E(XY)+E(Y^2)-(E(X)^2-2E(X)E(Y)+E(Y)^2)\\
&=Var(X)+Var(Y)-2(E(XY)-E(X)E(Y))\\
&=Var(X)+Var(Y),
\end{align*}
where the last equality holds because a family of independent random variables is uncorrelated.

Comment: Thank you very much. The square on the outside messed me up so bad that I had to ask.